# Do the Tauri (humans) use shuttlecraft?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

In Stargate SG-1 or Atlantis does the Daedalus class starships carry shuttle craft? I know they have transporter rings and Asgard transporters like in Star Trek, but even the Federation ships had shuttle craft. In Stargate Atlantis they use puddle jumpers granted they are not on a starship but serve the same kind of purpose.

Answer (score 13):

**It's not stated.** The class of ship certainly has bays that would be more than capable of supporting a puddle jumper but we don't ever see them using one.

On the official cutaway on the MGM website, the nacelles are labelled as F-302 bays, showing that the ship has orbit-to-ground capability without using the ring transporter or Asgard beaming technology.

[image]

Comment: Valorum,Yes I know the ship can land, however  there might be times when you do not want to alarm the population by having a large space ship land or maybe not showing you have beam/ ring transporters just yet. A shuttlecraft would be useful on any ship in my opinion.

Comment: @dean1957 - Between the Asgard beams, Goa'uld ring transporters, Tauri F-302s and the fact that the ship itself can land unnoticed at night, the ship has *lots* of ship-to-ground capacity.

Comment: I just think a shuttle or two would be nice to have on board. The Earth ships are run by the military so some of the technology or capability would be considered military secrets in some cases. So landing a small shuttle instead of the whole ship or beaming down would be more prudent in my opinion.

Comment: @dean1957 - Everyone cleared to be on that ship would be aware that beaming tech and rings exist.

Comment: @dean1957 The Daedalus is a battleship. That is a war ship. War ships throughout history have not had transport vessels because everyone that is on the ship is there for a duty. The only time they leave the ship is when they get R&R in port. The ship has the ability to take on civilians or VIPs, but that is not the craft's primary duty. That would be the primary reason you can not find a dedicated transport craft on the ship.

Comment: Season 10 Episode 1 Col. Carter was floating in space after the battle and the Odyssey could not beam her on board because it was not working. Transporter rings were useless. Col. Mitchell did a very dangerous maneuver by bringing her on board using the landing bay opening. I think if they had a shuttle craft it would had been easier.

Comment: @dean1957 Sure, but that was a unique situation. Otherwise, there would have been a different protocol in place to handle that situation better. There was a plan in place to handle that kind of situation, but Sam was just out of its scope. The military battleship is meant for war, not transport. You are talking about adding in features that are not typical and are out of place. Despite the craft being a battleship, had that been a more common situation they would have developed a different protocol to handle it.

Comment: @Odin1806 #1, why would it have to be a "dedicated" shuttle? #2, ever heard of helicopters? Plenty of IRL USN ships have a small chopper platform and an even smaller hanger for it, which does ASW but can also be used to... *Transport* personal, search and rescue, etc. Meanwhile actual aircraft carriers really do get fixed wing transports to and fro if not based on board, up to and including C137. So, yeah...it happens. It happens A LOT.

Comment: @JohnA - You are missing the classification of battleship. #1, that is the question. transport craft can come and go, but they are not assigned to a battleship. they come and go as needed. #2, as I mentioned before all ships have the ability to take on passengers while in transit, but that does not mean they always have them. #3,The purposes of transporting personnel, search and rescue, etc. are not the mission of a battleship. #4, Aircraft carriers are not battleships, hence why they are covered in aircraft and don't have cannons... so yeah, it doesn't happen.

Comment: @Odin 1806 - 1) Thats based entirely on the fact that IRL battleships had no aircraft (past tense since nobody but the US has used one in 30 years) but that's because NO battleship was ever designed *after* aircraft became capable. Thats important btw. 2) most examples (ie Trek) *have* ARMED shuttles. They're multi use. 3) IF any B.S. were designed to deploy helicopters they'd damn we'll be used as S&R *as needed*. 4) since BC304 class work alone they can't rely on shore or escorts for ANY of that. 5) it's a battle Cruiser; "BC" not BS304. So "you're missing the classification" :)

Comment: I don't want to get into a back and forth but war ships don't have transport aircraft. War ships are meant to destroy, not parlay. I will give you that the Daedalus is a battle cruiser, but that is simply because it also has attack craft on it - the F302. Still, there are no transport aircraft. And battleships are no longer necessary, that is why there are no more. However, there are still new vessels being developed that classify as war ships. If you are unaware the USS Zumwalt is another vessel that has no transport craft, but can take a helo on deck, because reasons. Wiki warship please

Comment: Man. Just because you say "warship" doesn't make transport irrelevant nor the lives of pilots disposable. The fact is they don't have them (yet, as of 2008) because they weren't a high enough priority not because they wouldn't be useful or effective. Certainly not because someone in-universe ever said "wait, oops, the *dictionary says that doesn't go on a warship*." The fact the Asgard transporters usually work makes up for it which is why it wasn't a priority to get 'em YET we see them use Jumpers *JUST LIKE THAT* half a dozen times. Because; reasons. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

We actually do see puddle jumpers operating this way from x304 in several SGA episodes just not as part of the regular compliment. This probably has more to do with their limited numbers (or bad writing) than anything else. The combination of their cloak and the fact of Wraith transporter jamming makes it an obvious combination. A small hyperspace scout would also make a lot of sense without stretching the definition of "shuttle" by much.

Earth doesn't have any pure transports during the series and never seems to have more than one or two Gou'ald cargo ships when they have any at all so it's not crazy to imagine they'd want to create home grown versions of those and jumpers just as much as the x302 fighter.

Even without shields or a cloak it'd make way too much sense for typical SG team operations to have a flying APC that fits through the gate. I was always a bit disappointed in SGA for never showing teams repelling out of a jumper into heavily wooded or mountainous terrain. The writers seemed to search for reasons to leave jumpers behind and walk through the gate.

It only took a couple seasons to patch those two gliders together into the x301 and another couple to finish the x302 prototype. From there it seems they deployed a hundred or so in the following few years. It'd be strange if they weren't about to introduce prototypes of small hyperspace cargo ship and/or a jumper analog by the time SGA ended. Given McKay's hyperspace jumper those could even be one and the same.

But as Valorum said we don't see it happen in the show. If events in the SG universe had progressed over the past decade it'd seem certain to happen by now.